# SQL server. Delete database after media disk failure

Tags: sql-server

I have a HyperV virtualized SQL Server

One of the phisical disks has failed, so one of the virtual drives in the SQL Server is out. I just want to restore a database in another virtual drive, but I can't, i guess because there is already a database with the same name.

How can I delete a database without having access to the storage?

Master database is perfectly accesible by the way.

Comment: Have you tried detaching the DB?

Comment: A simple drop table command did the job. Management studio delete table option wasnt working!!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your question referred to dropping databases. How would a drop table command allow you to drop a database?

Comment: My mistake! I meant drop database did the job! sorry for that :)